# Настройка IDE проекта | WebStorm | VSCode

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

Есть стурктура проекта:

**/src**

- /lib
- /components
- /global
- /hooks
- /utils

Можно ли как-то **указать IDE** откуда я могу **импортировать** данные?
Например, я хочу **запретить** импортировать из папки global в папку utils, но разрешить в components.

**Для чего это надо?** У меня проект-библиотека, и после сборки она очень странно импортирует данные. Появляются циклические импорты, которые кладут работу сборки.

Использую `madge --circular --extensions ts,tsx src` для поиска циклических импортов, и сборки проходят нормально. Получаются, что циклические импорты неявные.

Для сборки использую rollup.